# Is document.readyState === "interactive" fired before custom element gets instantiated?

Tags: javascript, html, chromium

Asking because it seems we have an issue there. MDN doesn't really answer this question: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState#values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how your JavaScript is loaded.

If your script is a module or is inline or has `defer`, the script will be executed after the document has been parsed. In this case `readyState` will be **interactive** in the constructor and connectedCallback of your custom element.

> **defer**
>
> This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before firing DOMContentLoaded.
>
> Scripts with the defer attribute will prevent the DOMContentLoaded event from firing until the script has loaded and finished evaluating.

Otherwise, the script will be executed immediately before the document has been parsed. In this case `readyState` will be **loading** in both the constructor and connectedCallback of your custom element.

> Scripts without async , defer or type="module" attributes, as well as inline scripts, are fetched and executed immediately, before the browser continues to parse the page.

###### Sources

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#notes